# Any way to check wether newer version of app is available?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am thinking to disable some functionality after newer version of the app is available. Is it possible? Am I violation any Apple rules?

The reason I wan to force users to upgrade their app.

I can setup a backend method for it, but maybe an official Apple provided way could exist also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the App Store API to check your app's version. Just replace `XXX` with your app's ID:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=XXX
```

The only way that this could be against regulations is if the user purchased the app and was guaranteed a feature and that feature was taken away purposely. Even with that you'd probably only get a bad rating.